# Android UI ListView

Tags: android, button, user-interface, expandablelistview

I have a quiz app with many categories:

Category 1

- List item 1
- List item 2

Category 3

Category 4

Category 5

- List item 1
- List item 2
- List item 3

So category either refers to a general non selectable category which is the category heading or an actual category. So for example within let's say that category 1 is fruits, there could be questions on apples and bananas. Apples and bananas would be selectable and also show how many questions were in category. But then category 3 would be vegetables which itself is selectable holding for example 100 questions.

Now is there the possibility of making this into an expandablelistview for each category. However categories that don't have additional questions are non expandable. Is there the possibility of putting buttons within the expandable list view or would these have to be separate? What about checkboxes?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create sectioned list easily by using following library.you can create it in six line

So you can have header for each category in listview

[sectioned List ibrary](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/simple-section-adapter)

### Example for Sectioned List

How to Implement this,

```
   // 1. Your data source
    String[] books = new String[] {
        "A Item", "F Item", "D Item", 
        "H Item", "T Item", 
        "A Item 1", "T Item 2"
    };

    // 2. Sort it
    Arrays.sort(books, 0, books.length, Collator.getInstance());

    // 3. Create your adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, books);

    // 4. Create a Sectionizer
    Sectionizer<String> alphabetSectionizer = new Sectionizer<String>() {

        @Override
        public String getSectionTitleForItem(String categoryName) {
            return bookName;
        }
    };

    // 5. Wrap your adapter within the SimpleSectionAdapter
    SimpleSectionAdapter<String> sectionAdapter = new SimpleSectionAdapter<String>(this, 
            adapter, R.layout.section_header, R.id.title, alphabetSectionizer);

    // 6. Set the adapter to your ListView
    setListAdapter(sectionAdapter);
```